# JSLink file location

Tags: document, pdf, jslink

I have JS file that can open pdf files into new windows, now I want to know how can I upload that to the document view? this is the AllItems.aspx file that display all the documents and this is my site collection sitename/September05TeamSite. I can't find the JSLink property on this page, I can only see the JSLink property on the Webparts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the page of AllItems.aspx in SharePoint Designer and then edit the webpart. You will find the JSLink option on the webpart inside AllItems.aspx for that webpart.

Alternatively, you can click the Library Tab, then "Form Web Parts" -> "Default Display Form" to edit the webpart of the default display form (AllItems.aspx). The JSLink will be in the webpart options of the webpart there.